# DynamoDb Conditional expression contains() function on String Set always evaluates to False

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to update an item in DynamoDb. The condition for update is that an input string (`myValue` in below example) should not be present in a string set (`mySet`). Here's the abstract code:

```
Map<String, Object> valueMap =  new ValueMap().withStringSet(":val", "myValue");
String updateExpression = "add mySet :val ";
String conditionExpression = "not(contains(mySet, :val))";
UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = 
    new UpdateItemSpec().withReturnValues(ReturnValue.NONE)
        .withPrimaryKey("HashKey", "h1")
        .withUpdateExpression(updateExpression).withValueMap(valueMap)
        .withConditionExpression(conditionExpression);
try {
    myTable.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
} catch (ConditionalCheckFailedException ccfe) {
    System.out.println("success");
}
```

The item already exists in the db. Now, no matter `myValue` exists in `mySet` or not, the condition expression always evaluates to true, thereby never leading to `ConditionalCheckFailedException`.
Is there something wrong with the way I am using the contains() function?

Ref: [DynamoDb ConditionExpression Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html#ConditionExpressionReference.Functions)

Comment: Is the item getting added to the set properly, irrespective of the conditional expression?

Comment: Yes, the item gets added to the set properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this was:

```
Map<String, Object> valueMap =  new ValueMap()
    .withStringSet(":val", "myValue")
    .withString(":val2", "myValue");
String updateExpression = "add mySet :val ";
String conditionExpression = "not(contains(mySet, :val2))";
UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec().withReturnValues(ReturnValue.NONE)
    .withPrimaryKey("HashKey", "h1")
    .withUpdateExpression(updateExpression).withValueMap(valueMap)
    .withConditionExpression(conditionExpression);
try {
    myTable.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
} catch (ConditionalCheckFailedException ccfe) {
    System.out.println("success");
}
```

i.e. Using a String (`:val2`) and a StringSet (`:val` of the same `myValue` and then using `:val2` in conditional expression and `:val` in update expression.

This is because update expression expects a StringSet to append to a set of string while the contains() function expects a String to check if it exists in a StringSet.